# Entity Framework and empty migrations class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my solution I have two projects: SharePoint and Class Library. In ClassLibrary is a class DBContext and models. "Enable-Migration" generated class Configuration.cs. Next, I created the first migration through the "Add-Migration Initialize" and it worked. My next step was to "Update-Database" everything was fine. But after a while I changed the model and I wanted to generate migration. Unfortunately, I get a blank method Up and Down. Entity Framework does not see my changes ... The models are written without annotations and Context it inherits DbContext and is written like this:

```
public class SchoolContext: DbContext 
{
    public SchoolContext (): base () {} 
    public DbSet <Student> Students; 
}
```

Models are written in this way:

```
public class Student 
{
   public int FirstName {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It may be that the changes did not result in a database change. What was the entity before you changed it?

Comment: Can you try to right click your class library and clean project?

Comment: Are automatic migrations enabled?

Comment: I clean solutionand rebuild and automatic migrations are disabled in Configuration.cs: `        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }`

Comment: Peter Smith - I add properties for example: in Student class

Comment: Try adding new class to your DbContext and see if it gets to migration script

Comment: Raderic - I try add new properties DbSet but this give my empty migrations class (empty up and down)

Comment: In the `DbContext` constructor you are not specifying the connection string, either from .config file or the connection string as the parameter to the `base` constructor.

Comment: I have connection string in App.config. Connection string name is is same as DbContext class. Update-Database is working correctly.

Comment: Try changing to public DbSet <Student> Students {get;set;} EF needs both the getter and setter for DbSet objects.

Comment: It was just an example.In the project (of course) DbSet is public. I made a small test on a different environment (I use the virtual machine to dev) and where everything works, or rather something to do with the environment. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 in Microsoft Windows Server 2012.